# Basis of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is the basis of a vector space always its minimum subspace?

Excuse me if my question is wrong but I study linear algebra atm

Comment: a basis is not a subspace.

Comment: It is wrong but that's not problem. The problem, perhaps, is that it shows there's some basic misunderstanding/ignorance of the very basics of linear algebra. A basis almost **never** is a subspace. What you can say is that a basis is a *minimal generating* set , or what is the same: a *maximal linearly independent* set.

Comment: Oh excuse me I meant to write the minimal generating set. Nice then thank you for your response

Comment: it is **a** minimal generating set, but it is in general not unique. There are many bases for a vector space, all with the same cardinality.

Comment: @argiriskar Fine, but there's usually not **the** minimal/maximal such set, but *a" minimal/maximal ...

Answer (score 1):

A basis is a minimal spanning set also called a minimal generating set. Being a spanning or generating set means linear combinations of elements in the set get you everything in the vector space. A minimal subspace will just be zero.